# Emacs visibility not working

Tags: org-mode, visibility

I tried `C-c C-x p` to set property as `VISIBILITY` and value as `folded`. The output looks like this:

```
* Org Headline Description
:PROPERTIES:
:VISIBILITY: folded
:END:
```

But when I close and reopen the file, this headline *still* shows up in its full unfolded state. What more do I have to do to open this header in folded state?

p.s.: My emacs version is `GNU Emacs 27.1`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What is the value of `org-startup-folded`? I'm guessing it's the default value of `showeverything`. That's the default in order not to surprise new users ("I added all this stuff to my file and now I can't see it: where did it go?"), but you might want to tweak that.

If you want to keep the global value unchanged, then try adding

```
#+STARTUP: showall
```

at the top of the file. See the [Initial visibility](https://orgmode.org/manual/Initial-visibility.html#Initial-visibility) section of the Org mode manual for other possible values.

Otherwise, do `C-h v org-startup-folded`, click the `Customize` button and experiment with the different values.

Comment: Thanks! That worked for me. But how do I set a global value?

Comment: Read the last sentence in the answer and do what it says.

Comment: Done. Thanks. :)

Comment: Alternatively, can also `(setq org-startup-folded 'content)` or `(setq org-startup-folded 'overview)` etc. p.s.: Don't like all the extra comments `custom` adds to the init file.

Comment: In general, it's safer to use `customize` (and in some cases, it is necessary). I use a separate customization file, as specified by the variable `custom-file`.  I then do `(load custom-file)` at the very end of my init file - and I almost never look at the custom file.

Comment: Ah - that is a neat trick (to set `custom-file` and load it). Indeed, it is safer to use `customize`. For example, I got `overview` spelled wrong once and the whole init file crashed.